# C# MVS2010 Draw lines & pictureboxes on panel while keeping the image seperate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, paint

Feel free to use any of the code for your own programs, any questions about the save as PDF will ofcourse be answered

I have strugled with a problem for quite some days now, what i want to make is the following :

1)  a program that can upload and image and display this image -> works with the code

2)  draw lines  on top of this image while beying able to remove them or change 1 of the 2 points of this line later -> still to make, plan to do this by checking if 1) makelines var = false 2) onclick mouse position is near the line point if so move mouse to the line points while holding mouse and than set point to mouse x & y.

3) i want to click on an icon on the left that i made, and drawing it on the uploaded image -> works

4) Problem ! - when i draw on this image it flickers, and so do the previous drawn lines and icons, the thing is that i've set the image as panel background so i could draw on it using panel's paint method, and i've succesfully stored the lines and icons into arrays, than after each finish of a line or icon, this will update showing me the image and on top of that the drawn lines and icons form the arrays. The fact that it flickers a lot is because i've used the Mousemove function to see where the line will be drawn and where the icon's will be placed, and to do that i'dd had to update it on mousemove but that Causes all the lines, icons, and background to refrech therefor flicking like crazy when i move.

here's my code,  MANY many thanks to anyone that can help me in the right direction // fix this problem or try to.

here's a video to make it clear what is happening and the problem.

My apologies if the code's not clear and if any questions please ask. this is a program my my dad's work , i normally design games and i'm new to C# therefor if i have made any mistakes tell me ! will be appreciated.

Kind Regards Jules Broeks
Game Technology Student
Netherlands

Video : http://youtu.be/bL7a-Lewp4Q

If you would need to see my array classes please tell me.

CODE :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace JulesIsDeBeste
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap newBitmap;
        System.Drawing.Image file;
        System.Drawing.Image image;
        System.Drawing.Image symbol1, symbol2, symbol3, symbol4, symbol5, symbol6, symbol7, symbol8, symbol9, symbol10, symbol11, symbol12, symbol13, symbol14, symbol15;
        System.Drawing.Image symbol31, symbol32, symbol33, symbol34, symbol35, symbol36, symbol37, symbol38, symbol39, symbol40, symbol41, symbol42, symbol43, symbol44, symbol45;
        System.Drawing.Image symbol46, symbol47, symbol48, symbol49, symbol50, symbol51, symbol52, symbol53, symbol54, symbol55, symbol56, symbol57, symbol58, symbol59, symbol60;
        System.Drawing.Image symbol61, symbol62, symbol63;

        private bool mouse_down = false;
        private Color col = Color.Black;
        private bool makeLine = false;
        int penwidth = 1;
        Pen blackPen;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        int x1;
        int y1;
        int x2;
        int y2;
        LineClass array = new LineClass();
        DrawIcon icon = new DrawIcon();
        System.Drawing.Image selectedIcon;
        private bool drawicon = false;


        public Form1()
        {
            symbol1 = JulesIsDeBeste.Properties.Resources.dice;
            symbol2 = JulesIsDeBeste.Properties.Resources.das;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    file = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    newBitmap = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    pictureBox1.Image = file;
                    pictureBox1.Height = panel1.Height;
                    pictureBox1.Width = panel1.Width;
                    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
                    panel1.Height = file.Height;
                    panel1.Width = file.Width;
                    panel1.BackgroundImage = file;
                    bitmap = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
                    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(panel1.ClientSize.Width - panel1.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height - panel1.Height, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));
                    pictureBox1.Hide();


                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Verkeerde format, kies een Image file", " -->  Error ! <-- ");

                }
            }
        }

        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String filename = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Opslaan als : ", "Wat moet je toch zonder Jules !", "", 250, 250);
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            //Choose the default start up folder
            string selectedFolder = @"C:\Dev";

            //Set that into the dialog
            folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = selectedFolder;

            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Grab the folder that was chosen
                selectedFolder = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

                // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
                // We print the number of files found.                
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(selectedFolder);

            }

            String abc = filename + ".pdf";
            panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(panel1.ClientSize.Width - panel1.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height - panel1.Height, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));
            image = bitmap;
            try
            {

                Document doc = new Document();
                doc.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle((panel1.ClientSize.Width - panel1.Width), panel1.ClientSize.Height - panel1.Height, panel1.Width, panel1.Height, 0));
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(selectedFolder + "/" + abc, FileMode.Create));
                doc.Open();
                iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                doc.Add(pdfImage);
                doc.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Saved At " + selectedFolder);

            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Log error;
            }
        }

        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            x1 = e.X;
            y1 = e.Y;
            mouse_down = true;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            mouse_down = false;
            if (makeLine)
            {
                array.addToArray(x1, y1, x2, y2, col, penwidth);

            }
            if (drawicon)
            {

                icon.addToArray(x2, y2, selectedIcon);
                panel1.Refresh();
            }


        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.X + "," + e.Y;
            if (mouse_down == true)
            {

                try
                {

                    x2 = e.X;
                    y2 = e.Y;

                    panel1.Refresh();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
            col = colorDialog1.Color;
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (makeLine && !drawicon)
            {

                try
                {
                         blackPen = new Pen(col, penwidth);
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);

                        for (int i = 0; array.linesCount() > i; i++)
                        {
                            blackPen = new Pen(array.getColor(i), array.getPenWidth(i));
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, array.getPointsX1(i), array.getPointsY1(i), array.getPointsX2(i), array.getPointsY2(i));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; icon.iconCount() > i; i++)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(icon.getIcon(i), icon.getX(i), icon.getY(i));
                        }
                        blackPen = new Pen(col, penwidth);
                }
                catch
                { }
            }

            if (!makeLine && drawicon)
            {
                try
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(selectedIcon, x2, y2);


                    for (int i = 0; array.linesCount() > i; i++)
                    {
                        blackPen = new Pen(array.getColor(i), array.getPenWidth(i));
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, array.getPointsX1(i), array.getPointsY1(i), array.getPointsX2(i), array.getPointsY2(i));
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; icon.iconCount() > i; i++)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(icon.getIcon(i), icon.getX(i), icon.getY(i));
                    }
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
            if (!makeLine && !drawicon)
            { }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!makeLine)
            {
                makeLine = true;
                drawicon = false;
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Honeydew;
                button2.ForeColor = Color.Red;

            }
            else
            {
                makeLine = false;
                button2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }

        }


        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            penwidth = trackBar1.Value + 1;
        }


        private void splitContainer1_Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            splitContainer1.Panel1MinSize = 250;
            splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScroll = true;

        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedIcon = symbol1;
            if (!drawicon)
            {
                drawicon = true;
                makeLine = false;
                button2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
            }
            else
            {
                drawicon = false;
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Honeydew;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No one is going to answer such question, split it and ask different questions instead.

Comment: Well to be Honest i´dd normally agree, but int his case i´ve read all related questions and tryed about 100 things that are allmost the same but non work for me since this program is not like any of the other ones... i´m hoping for some1 nice enough to take the time to look at it and help me out.

Comment: You need an undo/redo system, for re-arranging shapes you should draw 'handles' on places of interest for re-positioning them so they are user-friendly (otherwise you would have to precisely click the line). For flickering since you move the mouse a lot of times per second the panel does not have enough time to refresh, use a PictureBox which has double buffering and do draw only the last line over the composed bitmap, that is every time user starts a new line you render all the history as 1 bitmap, then refreshing only draws 2 items : the bitmap and the new line. Hope that makes senses :D

Comment: Dear Aybe,  thank you so much for looking into it, i've tryed a similar thing in the picturebox, but your solution seems to make sense, the question would than be, how do i render the history as 1 bitmap while preserving the ability to later chance the lines ?? if i make a bitmap like you say, of the screen and than render it i wouldn't be able to work the previous lines no more would i ?  and yes as you sed i was planning on drawing a rectangle around the point when the mouse came near and make that clickable.

Comment: Use a stack to represent undo/redo, every time a user draws a shape push it to the stack. Then you render all the items on the stack. When user undo something pop it from the stack etc. The first thing you want to push will be the bitmap. Now make a mechanism that previews the placing of the shape using a handle. Whenever the user create a new shape push the previous one on the stack etc. Keep the last bitmap preview on memory so you don't have to draw everything every time or do some XORing (see Wikipedia). Good luck :D